# How to pass a value from EJS to Node.Js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, ejs

I want to get the id value displayed on my EJS template to execute a query on MSSQL, but I don't know how to pass this value to my NODE function, my code:

```
function selected(id) { // id is the value that I want to get in EJS tamplate
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        sql.connect(config, err => {
            if (err) return resolve(err);
            var request = new sql.Request();
            request.query(`select * from license where license_id = ${id}`, (err, selected) => {
                if (err) return reject(err);
                var result = JSON.parse(Json.stringify(selected));
                resolve(result);
            })
        })
    })
}
```

And this is my table on Ejs tamplate that I want to get the value:

```
        <% for (var i = 0; i < data.recordset.length; i++) { %>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><a href="/seleted"><%= data.recordset[i].license_id %></a></th> <!-- This is the value that I want to get on the other side -->
            <td><%= data.recordset[i].request_approval %></td>
            <td><%= data.recordset[i].license_description %></td>
            <td><%= moment(data.recordset[i].beginning_date).format('DD/MM/YYYY') %></td>
            <td><%= moment(data.recordset[i].end_date).format('DD/MM/YYYY') %></td>
            <td><%= data.recordset[i].quantity %></td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
```

Comment: It'll be the same way you got `data` into your template.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an end point at your app something like a GET request with query string  /seleted?id="your_id"

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>request_approval</th>
        <th>license_description</th>
        <th>beginning_date</th>
        <th>end_date</th>
        <th>quantity</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% for (var i = 0; i < data.recordset.length; i++) { %>
<tr>
    <td><a href="/seleted?id=<%= data.recordset[i].license_id %>">id</a></td>
    <td><%= data.recordset[i].request_approval %></td>
    <td><%= data.recordset[i].license_description %></td>
    <td><%= moment(data.recordset[i].beginning_date).format('DD/MM/YYYY') %></td>
    <td><%= moment(data.recordset[i].end_date).format('DD/MM/YYYY') %></td>
    <td><%= data.recordset[i].quantity %></td>
</tr>
<% } %>
</tbody>
```

get your query string :

```
app.get('/seleted', function (req, res) {

    let id = req.query.id;
    var licence = await selected(id);

});
```